# Output of C preprocessor for IBM s390?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a bug report for a failure on an IBM s390 from a Debian maintainer. I'm pretty sure I know the issue, but I don't have access to s390 iron for testing. In addition, Debian QEMU's [qemu-system-s390x](https://superuser.com/q/973566/173513) does not appear to work under Debian 8 (also see [Debian Bug 799120](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=799120)).

Can someone please provide the following from an IBM s390 under GCC:

```
cpp -dM < /dev/null | sort
```

Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 2):

László Böszörményi of Debian graciously tested and reported a failure when he tested under S/390. Michael Tokarev of Debian, who is a QEMU maintainer, graciously provided the preprocessor macros for us in a private email because we were having trouble setting up the QEMU chroot environment under Debian 7 and 8.

Based on the information below, I think we are going with a feature test for endianess that uses the ISA and OS:

```
#if (defined(__s390__) || defined(__s390x__) || defined(__zarch__))
    //  Its an S/390
#endif
```

An just when I though I'd seen it all with respect to big endian, little endian, and bi-endian, I learn of `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__`... Maybe a compile time assert is in order to ensure we don't hit that corner case.

```
sid-s390x-chroot# cpp -dM < /dev/null | sort
#define _LP64 1
#define _STDC_PREDEF_H 1
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
#define __ATOMIC_CONSUME 1
#define __ATOMIC_RELAXED 0
#define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3
#define __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST 5
#define __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ 8
#define __BYTE_ORDER__ __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
#define __CHAR16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __CHAR32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __CHAR_UNSIGNED__ 1
#define __DBL_DECIMAL_DIG__ 17
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ ((double)4.94065645841246544176568792868221372e-324L)
#define __DBL_DIG__ 15
#define __DBL_EPSILON__ ((double)2.22044604925031308084726333618164062e-16L)
#define __DBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DBL_MANT_DIG__ 53
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __DBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __DBL_MAX__ ((double)1.79769313486231570814527423731704357e+308L)
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __DBL_MIN__ ((double)2.22507385850720138309023271733240406e-308L)
#define __DEC128_EPSILON__ 1E-33DL
#define __DEC128_MANT_DIG__ 34
#define __DEC128_MAX_EXP__ 6145
#define __DEC128_MAX__ 9.999999999999999999999999999999999E6144DL
#define __DEC128_MIN_EXP__ (-6142)
#define __DEC128_MIN__ 1E-6143DL
#define __DEC128_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000000000000000000000000000000001E-6143DL
#define __DEC32_EPSILON__ 1E-6DF
#define __DEC32_MANT_DIG__ 7
#define __DEC32_MAX_EXP__ 97
#define __DEC32_MAX__ 9.999999E96DF
#define __DEC32_MIN_EXP__ (-94)
#define __DEC32_MIN__ 1E-95DF
#define __DEC32_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000001E-95DF
#define __DEC64_EPSILON__ 1E-15DD
#define __DEC64_MANT_DIG__ 16
#define __DEC64_MAX_EXP__ 385
#define __DEC64_MAX__ 9.999999999999999E384DD
#define __DEC64_MIN_EXP__ (-382)
#define __DEC64_MIN__ 1E-383DD
#define __DEC64_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000000000000001E-383DD
#define __DECIMAL_DIG__ 36
#define __DEC_EVAL_METHOD__ 2
#define __ELF__ 1
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
#define __FLT_DECIMAL_DIG__ 9
#define __FLT_DENORM_MIN__ 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613e-45F
#define __FLT_DIG__ 6
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209289550781250000000000000000000e-7F
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282346638528859811704183484516925e+38F
#define __FLT_MIN_10_EXP__ (-37)
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435082228750796873653722224568e-38F
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __FP_FAST_FMA 1
#define __FP_FAST_FMAF 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR16_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LLONG_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_SHORT_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_TEST_AND_SET_TRUEVAL 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_16 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_8 1
#define __GCC_IEC_559 2
#define __GCC_IEC_559_COMPLEX 2
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 2
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 1
#define __GNUC_STDC_INLINE__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 5
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1009
#define __HTM__ 1
#define __INT16_C(c) c
#define __INT16_MAX__ 0x7fff
#define __INT16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT32_C(c) c
#define __INT32_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __INT32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT64_C(c) c ## L
#define __INT64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT8_C(c) c
#define __INT8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INT8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INTMAX_C(c) c ## L
#define __INTMAX_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ long int
#define __INTPTR_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INTPTR_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST16_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_FAST16_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST32_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_FAST32_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_FAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INT_FAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0x7fff
#define __INT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT_LEAST32_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __INT_LEAST32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT_LEAST64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_LEAST8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INT_LEAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __LDBL_DENORM_MIN__ 6.47517511943802511092443895822764655e-4966L
#define __LDBL_DIG__ 33
#define __LDBL_EPSILON__ 1.92592994438723585305597794258492732e-34L
#define __LDBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 113
#define __LDBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 4932
#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176508575932662800702e+4932L
#define __LDBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-4931)
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)
#define __LDBL_MIN__ 3.36210314311209350626267781732175260e-4932L
#define __LONG_DOUBLE_128__ 1
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffLL
#define __LONG_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __LP64__ 1
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1
#define __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__ 4321
#define __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ 1234
#define __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__ 3412
#define __PRAGMA_REDEFINE_EXTNAME 1
#define __PTRDIFF_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#define __REGISTER_PREFIX__
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 0x7fff
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_MIN__ (-__SIG_ATOMIC_MAX__ - 1)
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_TYPE__ int
#define __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_INT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_INT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 4
#define __SIZE_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__ 1
#define __STDC_IEC_559__ 1
#define __STDC_ISO_10646__ 201103L
#define __STDC_NO_THREADS__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_16__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_32__ 1
#define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __UINT16_C(c) c
#define __UINT16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __UINT16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __UINT32_C(c) c ## U
#define __UINT32_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define __UINT32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __UINT64_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINT64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT8_C(c) c
#define __UINT8_MAX__ 0xff
#define __UINT8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __UINTMAX_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINTMAX_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINTPTR_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINTPTR_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST16_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT_FAST16_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST32_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT_FAST32_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT_FAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST8_MAX__ 0xff
#define __UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __UINT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __UINT_LEAST32_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define __UINT_LEAST32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __UINT_LEAST64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_LEAST8_MAX__ 0xff
#define __UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__
#define __VERSION__ "5.2.1 20150911"
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __WINT_MAX__ 0xffffffffU
#define __WINT_MIN__ 0U
#define __WINT_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define __has_include(STR) __has_include__(STR)
#define __has_include_next(STR) __has_include_next__(STR)
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __s390__ 1
#define __s390x__ 1
#define __unix 1
#define __unix__ 1
#define __zarch__ 1
#define linux 1
#define unix 1
```